# What do I need to do in order to write my input on a new line in Java?

Tags: java, text, numbers

So after I input the numbers needed for the while instruction, it should display 
the result and then the "Enter your name here:" text.
Afterwards I should be able to input text, but apperantly I can't, it just displays the "Hello" message and jumps to the next instruction.

However, if I write the text right after the series of numbers, it works just fine. How can I make the program let me input text after the "Enter your name here" message?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class apples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner cristi = new Scanner(System.in);

        int age= 21, k=10, nr=1, sum=0, val=0;
        k=cristi.nextInt();
        while(nr<=k){
            val=cristi.nextInt();
            sum=sum+val;
            nr++;
        }
        sum=sum/k;
        System.out.println(sum);

        System.out.println(age>50 ? "You are old!" : "You are young!");

        tuna tunaObject= new tuna();
        System.out.println("Enter the name here: ");

        String a= cristi.nextLine();
        tunaObject.simpleMessage(a);

        System.out.println("Enter first name: ");
        String temp= cristi.nextLine();

        tunaObject.setName(temp);
        tunaObject.afisaj();         
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the line:

```
cristi.nextLine();
```

after the `while` loop to solve your problem.

**Edit:** @Xatyrian answer provides more context.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue about buffers and `Scanner`. To resolve your issue, just do `cristi.nextLine()` after each `cristi.nextInt()`so you clear the buffer.

For more info, you can look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Comment: Got it now. Thanks. I am in my first week of studying Java and I got used to C++, which didn't have such issues.